# OEM install asking for nameservers after oem-config-prepare

Tags: server, dns, dhcp, resolv.conf, oem

I'm trying to create an install image of server 15.10 that I can deploy to a few dozen machines by running through the OEM install, customizing packages and settings, then running "oem-config-prepare".

After running oem-config-prepare and rebooting (leaving out capturing the image for deployment elsewhere), while running through the install steps again, it asks me to manually input the name server addresses. If I leave it blank, resolv.conf does not auto populate from DHCP - even though DHCP is still assigning the rest of eth0's IP settings.

In the OEM install everything was set for DHCP and DNS auto populated, and that's what I want to carry over into the deployment image. I'll provide whatever further info might be needed, but does anyone have an idea as to what's going on to cause DHCP to work but resolv.conf to not populate once I run the install again after OEM prep?